# Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Double' with an argument list of type '(Range<Double>)'

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

i'm getting this error here (Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Double' with an argument list of type '(Range)') here

```
for dista in Double(0..<(car.distance)) //error here {

        }
```

where "distance" is of type Double.
How can i solve it?

UPDATE

var distance: Double?  is in a custom class "Car". I have a function that download for me different cars

```
    if let carsDownloaded = response.cars {
                    var number = cars / (models?.count)!
                    number = number == 0 ? 1 : number

                    let distanceC = carsDownloaded

         for car in distanceC {
                        for dista in car.distance! { 
   }
 }
```

cars are the cars that i can download, response chose if i really can download those cars and in the end response.cars are the cars that i will download. Now i would like to order in a filter those cars from nearest to the fairest but my problem is that i take the distance value from my position to a X car with external functions

```
func distance(from: CLLocationCoordinate2D, to: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> CLLocationDistance {
        let from = CLLocation(latitude: from.latitude, longitude: from.longitude)
        let to = CLLocation(latitude: to.latitude, longitude: to.longitude)

        return from.distance(from: to)

    }


    func didSelectt(car:Car) {

        guard let coordinates = car.location  else {
            return
        }
        self.destination = coordinates

        // update distance
        if currentLocation != nil {
            let dist = distance(from: currentLocation!, to: coordinates)
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you expect that `Double(0..<(car.distance))` does ?

Comment: i would like to do something like this "for dista in car.distance" but i got the error Type 'Double' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence' so i tried to change with that

Comment: `car.distance` is a *single number.* What exactly do you want to iterate over?

Comment: yes, it should throw an error. Here you are typecasting range to Double (which will certainly fail) and Double does not conform to Sequence protocol.

Comment: i updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of the `in` parameter in a loop must be a range of `Int`. Besides you cannot convert a range to a *single* type like `Double`

To iterate over a sequence != `Int` you need `stride`

```
let distance = 25.0

for dista in stride(from:0.0, to: distance, by: 1.0) {
    print(dista)
}
```

Comment: i updated the question if you can check